# Visual Studio cannot find Windows 10 mobile emulators

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-mobile

[image]

I tried:

- Repair Visual Studio
- Modify Visual Studio (selecting and unselecting W10)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE...\Windows Kits\Installed Roots\KitsRoot10: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the x86 Build Options instead of ARM. The emulators only show up in x86 Build Architectures. If you end up selecting x86 and they still don't show, you may need to reinstall your Windows 10 SDK and make sure you select the Windows 10 Emulators options so they can be downloaded for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to install the Microsoft Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile with this link

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=698769

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to complete delete all stuff related to `Windows 10 SDK` including all Emulators and then reinstall it again. By the way, Mobile Emulators will be available not in `ARM` tab, but `x86`.